# Ejecutar un archivo .exe o .bat alojado en un servidor remoto desde un navegador en el equipo cliente

Tags: php

Tengo un equipo con linux y el servicio samba configurado.
Desde windows he creado la unidad de red llamada P: que corresponde a la ruta a \ipdelequipolinux\carpetaderecursos,  de forma que yo puedo ejecutar desde el cmd tipeando P:\archivo.exe  o P:\archivo.bat.   Mi deseo seria poner ejecutarlos desde el equipo cliente con windows ya sea en Chrome o desde Edge accediendo por http.  Necesito que se monte la unidad P desde el navegador y luego que se ejecute ese archivo exe o el archivo bat.    Hay alguna manera de hacer eso en PHP o en algun otro lenguaje?.   Si he sido capaz de que se monte la unidad P en PHP, pero no soy capaz de hacer que se ejecute un bat o un exe alojado en ese servidor.  He probado esto:

```
<?php

{
  $letter = "P";
  $location = "\\\\192.168.6.10\\recurso";
  $user = "usuario";
  $pass = "clave";


  $outx=shell_exec("net use ".$letter.": \"".$location."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:yes");
  exec("P:\miarchivo.bat");
  echo "<pre>$outx</pre>";

}


?>
```

Comment: Hola, si las rutas están bien, intenta con shell_exec en lugar de exec.

Comment: No puedes, porque PHP se ejecuta en el servidor y `shell_exec()` ejecutaría el programa en el servidor, no en el cliente; por supuesto, solo en caso de que en el servidor esté configurada apropiadamente la unidad de red. Del lado del cliente, por cuestiones de seguridad, el navegador no te va a permitir ejecutar programas.

Comment: Hola,  gracias por las respuestas. Habria alguna forma aunque no fuera en PHP,  por ejemplo haciendose. en Javascript o cualquier otro lenguaje que me permita hacerlo?